# What's the most user-friendly best UI SVN client for Windows 7?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm coming from Versions for the Mac, so I'd like an SVN client that is comparable on the Windows 7 side. The easier to use and understand how it works quickly is what I'm looking for.

Comment: you might try [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), [smartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html), or [rapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 7):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). It's pretty self-explanatory, but start reading [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-quick-start.html) if you want details.

Comment: The latest version 1.7.2 has even been updated to work with the Windows 7 native UI.

Comment: TortoiseSVN doesn't have a UI - it's a shell extension only.

Comment: What about its repo browser?

Comment: TortoiseSVN does have a UI. Not sure what Erick is thinking of. Just do a Google Image search for "TortoiseSVN"

Answer (score 4):

Currently I'd suggest [SmartSVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/), available with both free and professional licenses.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how it compares to Versions, but I've always found TortoiseSVN to be really good.

Answer (score 2):

We have been using TortoiseSVN.  Works great.  I like the UI.

http://tortoisesvn.net/